# Checking if database exists or not in SQL Azure

Tags: c#, sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database

Could any one please tell me how to code whether a database exists or not in sql azure ?

Comment: Downvotes as its the first answer on a search on google for "sql azure check if database exists"

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried querying the sys.databases table? That should give you what you're looking for. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951625.aspx).

Note: You'll want to run this query against the Master database. Otherwise, you'll only see the name of the current database (and Master).

Comment: Here is a link relating to Azures security guidelines, which gives a clear sample.    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394108.aspx

Comment: It mean do we need to use following code that runs aganist master database:

Comment: ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
       Server server = new Server(serverConnection);

       // after this line, the default database will be switched to Master
       Database database = server.Databases["MyDatabase"];

       // you can still use this database object and server connection to 
       // do certain things against this database, like adding database roles 
       // and users      
       DatabaseRole role = new DatabaseRole(database, "NewRole");
       role.Create();

Comment: // if you want to execute a script against this database, you have to open 
       // another connection and re-initiliaze the server object
       server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();

       connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
       server = new Server(serverConnection);
       server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE TABLE New (NewId int)");

Answer (score 1):

`Select count(*) from sysobjects where name = 'testdb'` returns 0 if not found.
put the name of your Database and we will edit the script for you .. all you need to do is copy and paste ok..?
here are some additional things you could try as well

Method 1: Use sys.sysdatabases view

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sysdatabases where name=@testdb)
    PRINT 'The database exists' else PRINT 'The database does not exist'
```

Method 2: Use sysdatabases system table from master database

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE name=@testdb)
    PRINT 'The database exists' else print 'The database does not exist'
```

Method 3: Using of sp_msforeachdb

```
--If you dont get a message, the database doesn't exist
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)SET @sql='if ''?''='''+@ testdb+''' print ''the database exists'''EXEC sp_msforeachdb @sql
```

Method 4: Using sp_msforeachdb with information_schema.schemata

```
--If you dont get a message, the database doesn't exist
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)
SET @sql='if exists(select * from ?.information_schema.schemata wherecatalog_name='''+@ testdb+''') print ''the database exists'''
EXEC sp_msforeachdb @sql
```

Comment: What do you mean it will not work..? what is your table name..?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i think it work for checking the table exists or not. But i want to check whether database works or not

Comment: sorry ....But i think it work for checking the table exists or not. But i want to check whether database exists or not

Comment: what is the name of the Database..?

Comment: name of the database is testdb

Comment: Try to run some of the scripts now that your 'testdb' name has been added to the scripts

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists (select * from master.sys.databases where name = '[enter name here]')
```

Comment: so do i need to change [enter name here] with my database name?