# Checking if table exists or not in SQL Azure

Tags: c#, mysql, azure-sql-database

Could anyone help me in checking whether table exists or not in sql azure?

Comment: Are you asking this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915521/checking-if-database-exists-or-not-in-sql-azure

Answer (score 8):

Use this query -

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sys.tables t
JOIN
  sys.schemas s
    ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE
  s.name = 'dbo' AND t.name = 'table1'
```

...specify your schema and table name.