# Script for creating database if it doesn't exist yet in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database

This question may related to [Checking if database exists or not in SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915521/checking-if-database-exists-or-not-in-sql-azure).

In SQL Azure, I tried to use a script like this to check the existence of a database, and create the database if it doesn't exist yet (in both SQLCmd and SSMS):

```
IF db_id('databasename') IS NULL CREATE DATABASE databasename
GO
```

However, SQL Azure keeps telling me

```
Msg 40530, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The CREATE DATABASE statement must be the only statement in the batch.
```

While the same script did work on a local SQL express instance.

Does this mean it is not supported on SQL Azure? 
Or is there any work around?

Thanks in advance.

---

Eidt:
Let me clarify what I want to achieve: 
I want a script which will create a certain database only if it doesn't exist before. 
Is it possible to have such kind of script for SQL Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a similar problem.
It looks like we can do something with `SET NOEXEC ON`, as in the following [StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/13858/53767) answer.

```
IF (<condition>)
    SET NOEXEC ON
ELSE
    SET NOEXEC OFF
GO

CREATE DATABASE databasename
GO

SET NOEXEC OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It's saying you can't do theck and create in the same piece of sql.

i.e you need to do Select IF db_id('databasename')
test the whether it returns null, and if so then execute the create database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what I want to achieve is to have a script to create a certain database only if it doesn't exist. 
Is it possible to have such a script for SQL Azure?